# Fundamental domain for a $C_2$-action on a Stone space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, group-actions

The following result seems to be true (I can prove it, only quite indirectly):

> Let $X$ be a Stone space (i.e. a compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space) and $\sigma : X \to X$  be a continuous map with $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}$ and $\{x : \sigma(x)=x\}=\emptyset$ (i.e. a fixed-point-free $C_2$-action on $X$). Then there is some open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $X = U \sqcup \sigma U$.

Question 1. Is this well-known? Is there a reference for this result?

Question 2. There are counterexamples when $\sigma$ is allowed to have fixed points (Arens-Kaplansky, Topological Representation of Algebras, Section 8). Is there also a counterexample if $X$ is the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Does your indirect demonstration use boolean algebra?

Comment: The argument is as follows: $X \to X/C_2$ is a $C_2$-torsor. But $H^1(X,C_2)=0$ (for example since we may regard $X$ as an affine scheme and Serre has shown that on affine schemes the sheaf cohomology vanishes). Hence, the torsor is trivial, which is exactly what we want.